# React - How to add "key" when pushing to an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React v15.1

I am creating a table with a variable number of rows, depending on the data provided via `props`. Here is where I am (and it works fine):

```
getRows = () => {
  const rows = [];

  for (const col in this.props.tableRows) {
    if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(this.props.tableRows, col)) {
        rows.push(React.cloneElement(this.props.tableRows[col], {}));
    }
  }
  return rows;
}
```

I am working on making the console warnings disappear. This old favorite is appearing `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of 'TableData'.`

**What is the best way to add a key to cloned elements that I am pushing to an empty array?**

**OR** is there a better way to handle this data on dynamically-generated table rows?

This is for an upload dialog for contact information I am using in many places. It successfully performs as expected, just need to add a key...or make it even better.

Comment: `getRows=() => this.props.tableRows.map((item, index)=>React.cloneElement(item,{key:index}))` It's this more cleaner?

Comment: `col` is undefined. But, yes, map would be easier to use.

Comment: @Ursus What is a good alternative to using `key-{index}` in this circumstance?

Comment: Assuming you're using something like `rows.map(row =>...)`, something like `row.id` would work.

Comment: @Ursus Using `key={index}` is only an anti-pattern for uncontrolled components.  Controlled components, paired with a store like Redux, do not have this issue.  Also, I think you meant to post [this link](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318#.wqidnv2fi)?

Comment: Sorry about the link @MichaelParker and thanks for posting the correct one. I think you're right, but there's no sign of controlled or uncontrolled components, so I assumed the worst.

Comment: I just assumed that table rows would contain static information that wouldn't depend on something like an `index` supplied through props

Comment: I just figured out that my data from the API in `this.props.tableRows` renders exactly the same without mapping over it at all. I had to add a key to a static table header deeper in the component stack. React warnings tend to be vague.

I now understand how to use `.map` better. Thanks, y'all.

Answer (score 2):

@medet-tleukabiluly has the right answer:

```
keyed_items = items.map((item, key) => React.cloneElement(item, {key}))
```

as long as each item is an element (not just a string).

Answer (score 0):

It would probably make more sense to use the `.map` function and render JSX so you can easily assign a key to each table row.

```
function getRows() {
    const {tableRows} = this.props;

    return tableRows.map((row, index) =>
        <tr key={index}>
            // whatever else you wanted to add inside each row
        </tr>
    );
}
```

This is mostly just a guess for what you're trying to do - if it doesn't work for you, please post a comment that describes your problem in more detail and I can edit this answer to provide a better solution for you.

Comment: I can get it to work as expected with your code along with this `return tableRows.map((row, index) =>
      React.cloneElement(tableRows[index], {})
    );`
but it is still giving the same key warning.
When I tried to put a `<div>` in there (cannot use `<tr>` right there), it gave me no data from the state tree.